Derivative of normal distribution.
Say we have a set of random variables parameterized by the real valued parameter t (time) $X_t$.
Further we have $$X_t \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_x(t), \sigma^2_x(t))$$
for some differentiable functions $\mu_x, \sigma_x : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
My question is

What would the time derivative of this look like? Would it be another normal distribution?
If so, is there a closed form for $$ V_t = \mathcal{N}(\mu_{x'}(t), \sigma_{x'}^2(t))$$

Physically, let's say I am measuring the position of an object with some error, which I know to be normally distributed. What would the distribution of the errors of the velocity look like? Would it be normal? If so, what would be the mean and variance.
I don't know how to even begin looking for an answer to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I advise you to update your parameterization of Normal distributions so the second argument is a variance rather than a standard deviation. It will make answers much neater to write, which might incentivise authors.
